# lambda function in different lines

Tags: python

I am a complete newbie in python.

I start doing lambda functions and they end up a bit longer than my initial goal:

Can I split it in different lines for better readability?, like this:

```py
parts.map(lambda p: (p[0]\
                     ,p[1]\ 
                     ,int(p[1].split("-")[0])\
                     ,int(p[1].split("-")[1])\
                     ,p[2]\
                     ,float(p[3])\
                     ,p[4]))
```

or it defeats the purpose of using a lambda function?

I feel when I write it is ok to use lambda function in one line, is quick and good, but when I check again my code later I feel is not legible all of it in one line...

Comment: write a function with all that stuff inside, then call the function

Comment: FYI In Python, [list comprehensions are generally preferred over uses of `.map`](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: If it runs, then it is allowed, I'd say. Question is; would you want to? I think lambda's should be reserved for quick, on the fly computations/alterations, whatever. This feels like something that just would be better of as a function you call on your object.

Comment: if only readability is your problem then I suggest using `black` to format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not clearly readable as a simple one-liner, then it's not a good candidate for a lambda. Remember that the `lambda` statement is just syntactic sugar, technically it IS a function:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> bar = lambda: None
>>> 
>>> type(foo)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(bar)
<class 'function'>
>>>
```

So yes, in your example it does definitly "defeat the purpose of using a lambda function". As far as I'm concerned, if I had to maintain this code, I'd rather find something like:

```
def prepare(p):
   p1a, p1b = (int(x) for x in p[1].split("-"))
   p3f = float(p3)
   return p[0], p[1], p1a, p1b, p[2], p3f, p[4]


whatever = [prepare(part) for part in parts]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in style and readability I can't recommend the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) enough. Overall, it explains the best practices to write readable Python. 
It will in particular give you advice on where to put commas when you start a new line, when to use parenthesis and how and when to write to a new line.

On lambda functions in particular it states:

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that
>   binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.
>
> Yes:
>
> `def f(x): return 2*x`
>
> No:
>
> `f = lambda x: 2*x`

In your case, I would use a function instead.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly relevant to OP question as it treats different misuse of `lambda`...

Answer (score 1):

You could define a normal function and just use it in the map function if it gets too long.

```
def foo(p):
    '''your code'''

result = list(map(foo, your_list)) # the list wrapper to convert map object to a list
```